# Emacs as git editor, what is Rebase mode?

Tags: emacs, git

When I run git rebase -i I get the absolutely horrible Rebase mode in emacs.

This only accepts some pre defined commads like

c -> Pick

r -> Reword

etc...

Even if I change to text mode emacs auto-magically makes the git-rebase-todo file read-only. How can I disable it?

The only solution I have found is to use vim as editor (something I don't want, I like emacs in general)

Comment: I know sometimes it's frustrating, but try to keep questions and answers here objective

Comment: @Raystafarian Yes, you are right. Thanks for editing the question!

Answer (score 2):

The `rebase-mode` automatic activation is triggered by the `auto-mode-alist`
variable. You can try disabling it to edit `git-rebase-todo` files in
fundamental mode (no special shortcut, no automatic read-only flag, ...) :

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (delete '("git-rebase-todo" . rebase-mode)
                              auto-mode-alist))
```

---

On another note, you might want to use [`magit`](https://github.com/magit/magit)
to realize your git operation directly from within emacs.

Comment: When using magit, something of note / related. I was getting`Buffer is read-only: #<buffer git-rebase-todo>`, and `C-x C-q` wasn't helping (was getting strange errors). Turns out the latest magit handles keyboard shortcuts within the rebase buffer (`s` for "squash", `f` for "fixup", etc). You don't type in the buffer, you interact with it.

Comment: This solution appears to have no effect.  I have those lines in my .emacs file, and I still get the rebase mode.  This is with emacs 24.5.1.